# how assigning base class object to parent class reference works?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

Suppose we have a base class and parent class named `Child` and `Parent` respectively.

```
Parent b = new Child();
System.out.println(b instanceof Child);// prints true.
System.out.println(b instanceof Parent);//prints true.
```

So why both the statements results true?

Comment: Because Base is also a Parent, since it extends the class.

Comment: Consider the **is-a** rule for inheritance.  `Base` **is-a** `Parent`.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i am confused it would be nice if you provide me some written reference...to learn about this

Comment: Dog extends Animal. So a Dog *is an* Animal. instanceof tests this is-a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

If class B extends class A, then B is a A. Eg Circle is a Shape.

Being able to refer to an instance as if it were a parent class is one of the *requirements* of an object oriented language.

See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` checks the relationship 'IS' for the **dynamic** **type** of the object

```
Animal a = new Dog() //Dynamic type of a is Dog
d instanceof Animal // TRUE
```

Because Dog is an Animal.

So `instanceof` looks at the branch of Animal and find that Dog is a child of Animal therefore return true.

However:

```
a instance of Dog // FALSE
```

Since an animal is not necessarily a Dog

Conclusion: `X instanceof Y`, for this to be true, Y must be a parent of X or the same type of X in the same branch

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Read more [Oracle Java Tutorial - The Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

**Note:** When using the `instanceof` operator, keep in mind that `null` is not an instance of anything.

For example:

```
String name = null;
System.out.println((name instanceof String));  // prints false
```

---

You might interested in [Class#isAssignableFrom()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
Parent p = new Child();
System.out.println(p.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Parent.class)); // return false
System.out.println(p.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Child.class));  // return true
```